# Java return value dependent on occurence of cats and dogs in a string?

Tags: java, string

1. The user enters a string.
2. The program returns true if cats and dogs occur the same amount of time, else false.
3. **example**: `catcatdoghotdog` = `returns TRUE` since `cat = 2` and `dog = 2`

// My code

```
 public String three (String str) 
{
  int cat = 0;
  int dog = 0;

  for(int a = 0; a < str.length() - 2; a++)
  {
    if (str.substring(a, a+3).equals("cat"))
    {
      cat++;
    }

    if (str.substring(a, a+3).equals("dog"))
    {
      dog++;
    }
  }

  if(dog == cat)
  {
      return "TRUE";
  }

  else
  {
      return "FALSE";
  }
}

System.out.println("Number of times cat and dogs appear in your word: " , + response.three(word)); // doesn't work...
```

> **`ERROR`**: + operator is undefined for String argument.

Any Suggestions, really welcome

Comment: NO need of `,` in line
`System.out.println("Number of times cat and dogs appear in your word: " , + response.three(word));`

Answer (score 2):

To concat String and variables, use `+` is enough.Remove the `,`.

```
System.out.println("Number of times cat and dogs appear in your word: " + response.three(word));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Number of times cat and dogs appear in your word: "  + response.three(word));
```

**remove the `comma`**